# Run protractor test remotely

Tags: automation, remote-access, protractor

I'm a QA Engineer where I work and I want to enable all the other
team members to run the tests without me-  i.e - even when I'm not here- they can for example get to some url, enter the url of the environment they want to test and play the tests, without installing anything on their computers.
what would be the best practice?

thanks.

Comment: how are you doing this locally? I'm asking so I know if the same thing can be replicated remotely.

Comment: Hey, in order to run it locally I have installed npm, Webdriver (Selenium server), and protractor itself.

Comment: Hi @user2880391 , How were you able to achieve this I am looking for similar functionality . your help would be appreciated

Comment: I have created an instance of remote environment (mac OS - same as my private environment), and installed protractor and made sure I'm able to run the tests there (locally). then I created a bash script  that runs it and enabled running it remotely (ssh ...). then I decided to connect it to Teamcity as a new project (since we are already using Teamcity as our CI server). I've just managed to run it for the first time from Teamcity and I have a lot more work to configure it further.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) will do what you want.

In that situation I would:

- Install Jenkins on a dedicated machine (onsite or in the cloud), or try out a commercial Jenkins cloud provider
- Configure a Jenkins job that executes your tests (you can configure the tests to run on the same machine where Jenkins is installed, or if you would rather have Jenkins run the tests on a second machine, that's possible too)
- Show your team members how to access Jenkins and launch the test job (or, you can also configure your test job to run automatically at a certain time of day, or even better, when changes are made in your version control system)

Comment: thanks for answering. apparently I didn't have all the data. we currently use  Team City for compiling the source code. the question is then- what would be the best practice for running tests using Team city - protractor - selenium server - tests source codes combination? is anybody doing that already?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeamCity, but the same general steps used to set up a test environment for Jenkins probably apply - I wager you can set up a Protractor test environment on the TeamCity server (or on a TeamCity agent) as you've already done locally, then create a build in TeamCity that runs your tests.